# Issue casting to string in google sheets script

Tags: javascript, casting, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have the following **function** for a google sheets document:

```
function names(nameCells) {
  var roomieNames = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < nameCells.length; i++) {
    var str = String(nameCells[i]);
    var splitted = str.split(", ");
    for (k = 0; splitted.length; i++) {
      roomieNames.push(splitted[i]);
    }
  }
  return roomieNames;
}
```

The function is supposed take a list of cells with names that are comma separated and return and single list of all the names.

For example:

```
James
Reese, Peter
Ryan, Monica
Reba

Nick
```

Should produce

```
James
Reese
Peter
Ryan
Monica
Nick
```

However I seem to be having an issue casting the **cell values** to **string values** and it says "Internal error executing the custom function" without giving me any more specifics than that. The following more basic program does work as expected:

```
function namesSimple(nameCells) {
  var roomieNames = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < nameCells.length; i++) {
      roomieNames.push(nameCells[i]);
  }
  return roomieNames;
}
```

However the following produces the error seen in the comments in line 4:

```
function namesBroken(nameCells) {
  var roomieNames = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < nameCells.length; i++) {
    var splitted = nameCells[i].split(", ");  //TypeError: Cannot find function split in object James. (line 4).
    for (k = 0; splitted.length; i++) {
      roomieNames.push(splitted[i]);
    }
  }
  return roomieNames;
}
```

Which leads to me to believe I need to cast the object to a string but as stated above that doesn't seem to be working either.

I tried googling casting techniques and feel that this should work. I have also tried .`toString()`; with no luck. Can someone help me out please. Thanks :)

Comment: log name `nameCells[i]` (Eg `console.log(nameCells[i])`) to your browser console to see what type it is and what functions is has. Perhaps it has a `.value` or .`text` getter. Without knowing what `nameCells` is we are going to be of little help.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to get nameCells?

Comment: nameCells is the input from the speadsheet. I'm not sure how to use the console. It seems to give me this error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: nameCells is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this custom function works:

```
function namesSimple(values) {
    return values.toString().split(",").map(function (r) {
        return r.trim();
    }).filter(String);
}
```

In your spreadsheet enter

```
=namesSimple(A1:A20)
```

Comment: Thanks JPV, unfortunately I am planning on adding other functionality to this script that needs to handle the values of each cell individually so it will not work with the function provided above. I am still confused as to what is wrong with my above methodology, if you may be able to help me with that?

Comment: The above function is perfectly capable of handling all individual cells. As to your own code, I suspect that split() is called on an array. If nameCells is a 2D array, then the first loop will deal with the individual rows (not cells). If you want to split the cells you'll need to create another loop that loops through all columns of the rows (being processed by the first loop).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the nested for loop (I need to use any IDE to catch these mistakes)

```
function names(nameCells) {
  var roomieNames = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < nameCells.length; i++) {
    var str = String(nameCells[i]);
    var splitted = str.split(", ");
    for (k = 0; splitted.length; i++) {  //should be for (k = 0; splitted.length; k++)
      roomieNames.push(splitted[i]);  //should be roomieNames.push(splitted[k])
    }
  }
  return roomieNames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the api docs (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values) the response for a request of a range of cells is returned as a 'ValueRange' object.

The data is represented:

```
{
  "range": string,
  "majorDimension": enum(Dimension),
  "values": [
    array
  ],
}
```

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#resource-valuerange

With values being an array of `ListValue`: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.ListValue

The ListValues represent a `Value` object which will have one of the following values: (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Value)

```
null_value  NullValue   Represents a null value.
number_value    double  Represents a double value.
string_value    string  Represents a string value.
bool_value  bool    Represents a boolean value.
struct_value    Struct  Represents a structured value.
list_value  ListValue   Represents a repeated Value.
```

The docs say:

> Value represents a dynamically typed value which can be either null, a number, a string, a boolean, a recursive struct value, or a list of values. A producer of value is expected to set one of that variants, absence of any variant indicates an error.

Comment: Hi, I went through the process you've outlined above, but I'm sorry but I don't actually understand how I can use any of that information to understand or solve the problem that I'm having